# 2002 Ford 3.0 Won`t Start until 3rd try every time

Tags: ford, starting, troubleshooting, ranger

Tried checking everything but to no avail. Been ongoing for about a year since its not problematic I`ve let it go until more info on the subject was available. Well now have had to replace the engine with a used one that I got to drive and had no problems. All components from the used motor were used including the Mass air flow. I thought it was cured after that but the starting problem came back like a ghost after 3 days. [I reused the original PCU ] Does any one have any insight on what I should be looking for ,some say the mechanical key switch but I think not. Note after a time it would sometimes start on first try after driving a few blocks to gas station but not always. EDIT to post 3 days ago after a year of starting on 3rd try only I decided to extend the cranking time witch I tried before and didnt work also I dont like to do because both motors start right now usually. but for the last 3 days its been starting on 2nd try with a 2 sec. bump . Kind of an annoying problem witch I`ll be looking for the answer long after this vehicle is gone.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the exact model of your Ford?

Comment: Hello it is a 2002 ford ranger XLT , 3.0 reg gas motor

Comment: When you say won't start, is that doesnt crank at all (no starter action) or does it just crank with no start?

Comment: It cranks fine , just that even with a slight amount of extended cranking it doesnt want to start until 3rd time. I usually just bump start it because that is all it really needs. Today out of the blue I decided to crank it for about 2 seconds and for now its starting on 2nd try .

Comment: Edit Im going to update the problem, 3 days ago i pulled the steering wheel to change cruise control buttons on steering wheel . It went without a hitch. well know my motor wants to start on 1st or 2nd try always now so I got slight improvment from that unrelated repair . But why?